# Manipulating Results Array for Multiselect—CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to populate a multiselect in my view with the results from a query to the database. Sorry if this is a very basic question—I'm a bit new to CodeIgniter and MVC.

My model simply gets all records from a table:

```
function getAll() {
            $query = $this->db->get('example');
            return $query->result_array();
    }
```

I then hope to pass the results to my view to populate a multiselect form element. However, the associative array that is returned does not provide the results I'd like.

What I get:

```
    [0] Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Bob
```

What I'd like to get:

```
[0] Array
    (
        [6] => Bob
        [7] => Linda
```

Am I missing something with my query that would achieve my desired results? Should I just use a `foreach` to create a new array that will be formatted the way I would like? If so would this `foreach` belong in my controller or view.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getAll()
{
    $items = $this->db->get('example')->result_array();
    if(empty($items))
        return array();

    $res = array();
    $i   = 0; 
    while($i < count($items))
    {
        $res[$items[$i]['id']] = $items[$i]['name'];
        ++$i;
    }

    return array($res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be to use active record, because it just gets the data from the column 'name' in your table)

```
$this->db->select('name')
         ->from('example');

return $this->db->get()->result();
```

If you were going to use a foreach loop, if you process the results in the controller  you would have to process them again in the view, so you may as well send the entire result array to the view and process them in the view. This is useful if you need to use most of the columns of one particular table in your view.